# Drupal 8 autoload don't load custom class

Tags: php, drupal, autoload, drupal-8

I recently decided to develop a new website with drupal 8 (i never used drupal 7 or other version). 
I had to create a module and i need a custom class in this module and i create a service to use it. But i've an error, my custom class is not find.

When i had a require of my class in the autoload.php, it's work. So my service is correct but my class is not include in my autoload.

Anyone have a solution for my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you "use" the class? Like that:

```
use Drupal\your_namespace\yourClass;
```

Of course your class needs a namespace to make this work.

Comment: Yes i used it, and it's work when i use a require in my autoload file

Answer (score 1):

you need follow PSR4  rule, if your class is defined in module, you should put  your class file into the correct folder structure , for example if your class namespace defined as  "Drupal\your_module_name\yourClass" , the file folder structure should be:  modules\your module name\src\ (your Class file)